# Safari Developer tools keep crashing when trying to inspect element

Tags: angularjs, safari

I'm creating a website using Angular.js and have primarily been building it using Chrome, but now I have gone to test some features in Safari (on OSX Mavericks, safari Version 7.0.1) and when I try to open the developer tools they keep crashing or are un responsive.

I have tried various methods of loading up the dev tools and none of them seem to work. For example, opening the dev tools by right clicking on an element and clicking inspect element doesn't work, and neither does opening the console via the Developer tab.

I have tried disabling extensions, but that had no effect.

If anyone has any ideas I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Is this only a case for angular webistes? Did you try debugging gmail just to see if it's angular in particular that crashes it and nothing browser instance specific?

Comment: I appreciate your warm welcome, I never seen such a warm regard here for trying to be helpful, it was a really pleasant introduction and I want to thank you for taking your time to write - at last the end of the questions reads "If anyone has any ideas I would be extremely grateful!"

Comment: Hey, so I have just tried using the dev tools in safari on my site for the first time since I asked the question and it seems that since safari got bumped a version (now 7.0.2) these issues have gone. Thank you for your suggestion though. I'm going to answer and close this question as I don't think its relevant any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like since safari has been upgraded to 7.0.2 this issue has been fixed. It seems that the devtools now work completely fine.

Comment: Awesome, that was an easy fix after all :-)

Comment: Not here.  I haven't the foggiest why, either